# how can I find out the number of questions in anime & manga

Tags: support

I was browsing some questions on Anime & Manga (AM).
Just out of curiosity, I am wondering if it is possible for a normal user to  find out the total number of questions on AM now?

I am sorry for the silly question if it violates the rules here.

Thank you.

Kitty

Answer (score 2):

there is 7,976 questions currently (24/06/2017 5:00 PM GMT+10) on Anime and Manga. this can be seen by going to the Questions link and looking under where Ask a Question link is (a bit to the left)

[image: page screenshot]

Comment: I've always wondered - does this account for deleted questions as well?

Comment: @Gallifreyan i don't believe so since deleted questions usually don't appear on the site (with some exceptions such as the front page not being updated or in mod tools). the number may be a few hundred off just from the deleted ID Requests if we want to count deleted questions.

Comment: @Gallifreyan It does not. To get the total number of questions ever posted on this site, you can use SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/688101. 3153 of our deleted questions (about 58%) are [identification-request] questions.

Comment: @senshin wow, i really underestimated how many there was

Comment: @senshin also if i recall correctly SEDE don't use live data as such it may be out of date depending on when you run it

Comment: @Memor-X SEDE gets a fresh extract each week, so it's never more than 7 days out of date. You can see when the last update was if you go here: http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq. (FWIW, I got the number "3153" by using my magical diamond moderator powers to use the site's search feature to find deleted posts, so that figure is up-to-date.)